# How to decompose an integer in two for grid creation

Tags: algorithm

Given an integer N I want to find two integers A and B that satisfy A × B ≥ N with the following conditions:

1. The difference between A × B and N is as low as possible.
2. The difference between A and B is as low as possible (to approach a square).

Example: 23. Possible solutions 3 × 8, 6 × 4, 5 × 5. 6 × 4 is the best since it leaves just one empty space in the grid and is "less" rectangular than 3 × 8.

Another example: 21. Solutions 3 × 7 and 4 × 6. 3 × 7 is the desired one.

A brute force solution is easy. I would like to see if a clever solution is possible.

Comment: Condition 1 is more important than condition 2?

Comment: I think so. Perhaps an user selectable factor for each condition. For instance, try to minimize a cost function given by:

Fac1 * Func(A X B - N) + Fac2 * Func(A - B)

Comment: For 21 you give 4 x 5 as a solution but 4 x 5 < 21 so it isn't a possible solution.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you wish to minimize difference between square matrix `ceiling(sqrt(N))` and rectangular matrix AxB?

Comment: For N = 34 do you want 2 x 17 or 7 x 5?

Comment: Fixed the example. For N = 34, 7 x 5, since it more like a square.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Easy.

In pseudocode

```
a = b = floor(sqrt(N))

if (a * b >= N) return (a, b)

a += 1
if (a * b >= N) return (a, b)

return (a, b+1)
```

and it will always terminate, the distance between `a` and `b` at most only 1.

It will be much harder if you relax second constraint, but that's another question.

Edit: as it seems that the first condition is more important, you have to attack the problem
a bit differently. You have to specify some method to measure the *badness* of not being square enough = 2nd condition, because even prime numbers can be factorized as `1*number`, and we fulfill the first condition. Assume we have a badness function (say `a >= b && a <= 2 * b`), then factorize `N` and try different combinations to find best one. If there aren't any good enough, try with `N+1` and so on.

Edit2: after thinking a bit more I come with this solution, in Python:

```
from math import sqrt

def isok(a, b):
  """accept difference of five - 2nd rule"""
  return a <= b + 5

def improve(a, b, N):
  """improve result:
    if a == b:
       (a+1)*(b-1) = a^2 - 1 < a*a
    otherwise (a - 1 >= b as a is always larger)
      (a+1)*(b-1) = a*b - a + b - 1 =< a*b

    On each iteration new a*b will be less,
    continue until we can, or 2nd condition is still met
  """
  while (a+1) * (b-1) >= N and isok(a+1, b-1):
    a, b = a + 1, b - 1

  return (a, b)

def decomposite(N):
  a = int(sqrt(N))
  b = a

  # N is square, result is ok
  if a * b >= N:
    return (a, b)

  a += 1

  if a * b >= N:
    return improve(a, b, N)

  return improve(a, b+1, N)

def test(N):
  (a, b) = decomposite(N)

  print "%d decomposed as %d * %d = %d" % (N, a, b, a*b)

[test(x) for x in [99, 100, 101, 20, 21, 22, 23]]
```

which outputs

```
99 decomposed as 11 * 9 = 99
100 decomposed as 10 * 10 = 100
101 decomposed as 13 * 8 = 104
20 decomposed as 5 * 4 = 20
21 decomposed as 7 * 3 = 21
22 decomposed as 6 * 4 = 24
23 decomposed as 6 * 4 = 24
```

Comment: @aaa: the `a >= b && a <= 2 * b` is just an example one.

Answer (score 1):

I think this may work (your conditions are somewhat ambiguous).  this solution is somewhat similar to other one, in basically produces rectangular matrix which is almost square.
you may need to prove that A+2 is not optimal condition

```
A0 = B0 = ceil (sqrt N)
A1 = A0+1
B1 = B0-1
if A0*B0-N > A1*B1-N: return (A1,B1)
return (A0,B0)
```

this is solution if first condition is dominant (and second condition is not used)

```
A0 = B0 = ceil (sqrt N)
if A0*B0==N: return (A0,B0)
return (N,1)
```

Other conditions variations will be in between

Answer (score 0):

```
A = B = ceil (sqrt N)
```

Comment: No, I thought that but it doesn't produce an optimal answer (it fails on 23 for example).

Comment: You need to define your cost function better, as palswim mentions.